# Handle modal form flash

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-xe2

I'm created custom form with : `BorderStyle` is `None` and use one shape for tittle background.
i want simulate flash form when this form showing `Modal` and user click in parent window.
for example change fill color of this shape when flashing form.
useing `Activate` and `DeActivate` events of form, works only in my application and when switch betwen forms.

Comment: Asking how to visually indicate flashing, or how to detect clicking on parent?

Comment: :How to handle flashing , and set my colors to shape for show flashing my form. when form border is set to none , form not flash for user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'm found my answer :

```
type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    shp1: TShape;
  public
    procedure WMNCActivate(var M: TWMNCActivate); message WM_NCACTIVATE;
  end;

procedure TForm2.WMNCActivate(var M: TWMNCActivate);
begin
  inherited;
  if M.Active then
    shp1.Brush.Color:= clLime
  else 
    shp1.Brush.Color:= clBlack;
end;
```